# extracting and adding a tag based on the condition

Tags: javascript

I have a below function where i need to add a tag between a valid regex.

```
const addValidTag = (text) => {
  let regex = /(\+)?(91)?( )?[789]\d{9}/g
   if(text.match(regex)){
     // add the tag with div and return
     
   }else {
     return text
   }   

}
```

These are the valid cases which i am trying for and it should return as the expected output

```
7013121114   => <div>7013121114</div>
joe 7013121114  => joe <div>7013121114</div>
joe 7013121114 joe  => joe <div>7013121114</div> joe
joe7013121114joe  => joe<div>7013121114</div>joe
joe<br/>7013121114joe => joe<br/><div>7013121114</div>joe
joe<br/>+91 7013121114joe => joe<br/><div>+91 7013121114</div>joe
```

how can i achieve this, any help appreciated

Comment: have you tried [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Comment: Do you want actual DOM elements or just HTML strings?

Comment: @Phil Strings only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) here

```
/[+]?(?:91\s?)?(\d+)/
```

```js
const arr = [
  "7013121114",
  "joe 7013121114",
  "joe 7013121114",
  "joe7013121114joe",
  "joe<br/>7013121114joe",
  "joe<br/>+91 7013121114joe",
  "joe<br/>0001231235216743",
  "joe<br/>+917013121114joe",
  "joe 7013121114 joe",
];

const result = arr.map((s) =>
  s.replace(/[+]?(?:91\s?)?(\d+)/, (...args) => {
    const numbersCount = args[1];
    if (numbersCount.length === 10) return `<div>${args[0]}</div>`;
    else return args[0];
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: But this  should not wrap a div for this case joe<br/>0001231235216743, which is not a actual valid 10 or 12(optional) digit phone number. It should return the same no need to wrap a div

Comment: @dev answer updated. Is this what you want

Comment: it works, thanks just one doubt, "joe<br/>+917013121114joe", if there is no space between the country code and number as its a valid how should i do the change to regex

Comment: just change it to `/[+]?(?:91)?\s?(\d+)/`

Comment: Answer updated with this requirement. I hope this is what you want...

Comment: Thanks, But its breaking on this test   "joe 7013121114 joe", should  get as "joe <div>7013121114</div> joe" but getting "joe<div> 7013121114</div> joe", the space between starting div and number

Comment: Updated again. Have a look

Comment: okay thanks how should i mention a limit for example min and max ? for the regex

Comment: you can use quantifiers `\d{3,5}` means number should be in between range `3` and `5`. [Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers)

Comment: /[+]?(?:91\s?)?(\d{3,5}+)/ like this ?

Comment: yup, but then you don't need `+` here

Comment: so in this what should be the quantifier seeing the cases , like either 10 or 12 ?

Comment: Not possible for `10` or `12`. Quantifiers is in range like between `10` and `12`. Read the link that I've provided in earlier comments

Comment: so basically the regex should match a valid starting indian number like 6,7,8,9 and it should have 10 numbers and country code is optional between a srtring or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var matches = str.match(regex);
              
if (matches) {
  let tempString = '<div>' + matches[0] (or use foreach) + '</div>';
  text.replace(matches[0],tempString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` the text based on output of regex, and manually concatenate the parts of string.
Also, I have added an ternary, to check if there is an empty space in string, and add it accordingly in the output.

```js
const addValidTag = (text) => {
  let regex = /(\+)?(91)?( )?[789]\d{9}/g
   if(text.match(regex)){
   let s = text.match(regex)[0];
   let m = text.split(s);
   let out = m[0] + (text[3] ==" " ? " " : "") + "<div>"+s+"</div>"+m[1];
     return out
   }else {
     return text
   }   

}

const arr = [
  "7013121114",
  "joe 7013121114",
  "joe 7013121114",
  "joe7013121114joe",
  "joe<br/>7013121114joe",
  "joe<br/>+91 7013121114joe",
  "joe<br/>0001231235216743",
  "joe 7013121114 joe"
];

arr.forEach(e=>console.log(addValidTag(e)));
```

Comment: If i give an input "joe 7013121114", it should give back in joe <div> 7013121114</div>, but its giving as joe<div> 7013121114</div>, the space

Comment: @dev I have updated the answer. Please check .

Comment: But if it starts with 7, 8, 9 and have more than 10 or 12(including country code ) also its returning   "joe 701312111412313123 joe" => joe <div> 7013121114</div>12313123 joe , which is wrong isn't